# added vlan interface, main host not reachable

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vlan

I have a VM server running Ubuntu on the `192.168.1.0/24` network. I am trying to add a vlan tagged subinterface that will be used for a VM that will be in a DMZ on my network. I added the subinterface first with `sudo vconfig add enp2s0 30` then with the following in the `/etc/network/interfaces` config

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo br0
auto enp1s0
iface lo inet loopback

###bridge interfae for vm's
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports    enp2s0
    bridge_stp      off
    bridge_maxwait  0
    bridge_fd       0
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    gateway 192.168.1.1

###power-fail backup NIC
iface enp1s0 inet static
  address 192.168.40.2
  network 192.168.40.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0

#suberinterface for VLAN segregated VM's
auto enp2s0.30
iface enp2s0.30 inet dhcp
    vlan-raw-device enp2s0

###network shim for dockers
auto macvlan0
iface macvlan0 inet static
    pre-up ip link add link br0 name macvlan0 type macvlan mode bridge
    address 192.168.1.42
    network 192.168.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0

###routes for dockers
post-up route add -host 192.168.1.16 dev macvlan0
post-up route add -host 192.168.1.43 dev macvlan0
```

Here is my `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.41 
192.168.1.0/24 dev macvlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.42 
192.168.1.16 dev macvlan0 scope link 
192.168.1.43 dev macvlan0 scope link 
192.168.30.0/24 dev enp2s0.30 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.30.2 
192.168.40.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.40.2
```

And here is my existing `ip addr`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:e8:94:f0:55:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.40.2/24 brd 192.168.40.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::36e8:94ff:fef0:553f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:12:aa:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:12:aa:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.41/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1e1b:dff:fe12:aa73/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: enp1s0.30@enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:e8:94:f0:55:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enp2s0.30@enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:12:aa:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.30.2/24 brd 192.168.30.255 scope global enp2s0.30
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1e1b:dff:fe12:aa73/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: macvlan0@br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:8e:07:8f:0f:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.42/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global macvlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::308e:7ff:fe8f:f61/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

After resetting the network service the interface comes up and gets an IP address. However, now I can't reach any of the VMs running on the parent interface `enp2s0`. Do I need to add some routing to the parent `enp2s0` interface? This server has two NICs. The primary NIC is `enp2s0`. `Enp1s0` serves as a backup NIC to speak with the UPS in the event of a power failure.

Comment: It might be a typo, but the base interface in your question is enp**1**s0. Can you show the entire *interfaces* file, and the output of *ip address* when the VM is not accessible?

Comment: Thanks, but not a typo. I have dual NICs. enp1s0 is a powerfail NIC for tying into the UPS. enp2s0 is the main network NIC

Comment: So you build a VLAN interface named *enp2s0.30* on top of *enp1s0*? Possible but very confusing.

Comment: No everything would be on `enp2s0`, but I just edited the question and changed everything to `enp1s0` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Do all now-unavailable VMs on the "parent" interface use a bridge in which that "parent" interface also participates? I mean, please provide more detailed network configuration of your system, 3 lines of interfaces file is insufficient. At least we need an output of `ip addr` and `ip route` commands.

Comment: Yes. All the current VMs use br0. I'll add some more info about interfaces and routes.